# NSIS: Reading from a file at compile time

Tags: nsis, compile-time

I want to read some values from a file (config.json) into some variables when I compile my nsis script.
How can I possibly do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you want to do it in this way? Give us some example. Maybe you can replace those values using some building mechanism, for example `ant`?

Comment: I just want to read the values from config file at compile time and kinda embed it in the exe, so that my exe is not dependent on some external config file.

Comment: Does it have to be JSON? You couldn't arrange for it to be an NSIS header file (`.nsh`, containing things like `!define XYZ ABC`) or pass them to the compiler (`makensis /DXYZ=ABC`)? Or do you have some other language (e.g. Python) that you are already using which you could use to achieve this?

Comment: @ChrisMorgan json file is preferred for what I am doing. And No, I am not using any other language, just nsis.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `!include` command can include any file (at compile time) at the point where it is placed in the nsis script. But the included file must be compliant with the nsis syntax (e.g. it should `!define` some values).

The `!execute` command could help you: if you need absolutely to process a json file you could code a third-party batch command file to pre-process the json file and translate it into a suitable nsis file.

Comment: What I'm doing right now is something similar to this. I am making a `readconfig.exe` (and executing it from script at compile time using `!execute` ) that does the reading work from `config.json` and write to a `config.nsh` , which I am including in my original nsis script. But in this approach I have to use an extra `config.exe` which i dont want. So, looking for some other better options.

Comment: @smilepleeeaz: well, that's about as good as you're going to get.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `!define` to pass some value which can be used in compile time. For example lets imagine that you have got this code in you nsis source file:

```
!define PATHTOFILE "C:\thisfilewillbedeleted.ext"
Delete $PATHTOFILE
```

If you want to change this walue on compile time you can call nsis in this way:

```
makensis /DPATHTOFILE="C:\otherfiletodelete.ext"
```

**[EDIT]**

If you got *.json file which is generated using external tool and you must use this kind of file I will suggest you to use some building system, for example `ant`. You can create `build.xml` which read, parse data from json file and then write those data to `*.nsh` file. I think it will be better and cleaner than do it all in nsis script.

Comment: If this one helped you, you should check it as helpful ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to parse your json file on runtime, you can use `!define` with the `/file` option:

```
!define /file OPTIONS json.txt
```

It will define OPTIONS with the content of json.txt.

If you want to utilize your json file in compile time to alter the generated exe, then you need some kind of precompiler, which is what you're actually doing.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the !searchparse command with the /file switch.

Example :

# search filename.cpp for a line '#define APP_VERSION "2.5"' and set ${VER_MAJOR} to 2, ${VER_MINOR} to 5.

!searchparse /file filename.cpp `#define APP_VERSION "` VER_MAJOR `.` VER_MINOR `"`